# how to Change glassfish application url

Tags: web-applications, glassfish-3

My current glassfish application can be accessed using this url

localhost:9595/apex

I want to change it to

localhost:9595/pls/apex

what i need change in this case.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the context-root for your application by adding a context-root in `glassfish-web.xml` (If you don't have this file in your project, create it in the WEB-INF folder) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/pls/apex</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

**Update**: If this doesn't work you can try to use a `sun-web.xml` like it is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16216323/using-the-context-root-from-glassfish-web-xml-in-glassfish3).

Comment: @unwichtoch 
i create jlassfish-web.xml in my current WEB-INF folder and put above code
but it gives error only..This techniq don't work

Comment: The requested resource () is not available.

i tried using both ways sun-web.xml and glassfish-web.xml inside WEB-INF
what changes i need

Comment: I am trying to do the same.. what I did is to change the folder name in glassfish\domains\domain1\autodeploy\ path. I edit here my project it was Project1_war to  enterprise_war and now I can access like http://localhost:8080/enterprise/

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively to using the descriptior `glassfish-web.xml` you can explicitly definde the context root at deploy time by using the --contextroot switch of asadmin:

```
asadmin deploy --contextroot="/pls/apex" apex.war
```

or fill the appropriate context root field in the admin console.

Comment: @unwichtoch, Markus i used both ways but glassfish gives following error, thanx for your reply ..please give me solution 


java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3990: getWriter() has already been called for this response