# Ways of deploying in Payara Micro under a certain context root

Tags: deployment, contextroot, payara-micro

I'm looking for ways to deploy an application in Payara Micro under a specific context root (ideally an empty context, so the application runs at root).

As far as I know there are two methods:

1. Use an `.ear` file and specify the context root in the application.xml file:

   `<context-root>/</context-root>`
2. Start Payara Micro and deploy programmatically

   `PayaraMicroRuntime instance = PayaraMicro.bootstrap();
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream("thewar.war")
   instance.deploy("name", "contextroot", is);`

Is there any other way I'm missing? Both versions above are not suitable for me in my current setup.

Comment: What is your current setup? The way to do this with a WAR file is with a `glassfish-web.xml` file, as in this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18358642/212224

Comment: Thank you, @Mike, for your comment. It looks like this should work, but payara micro seems to not read the `glassfish-web.xml`. I have it packaged in the war file at `META-INF/glassfish-web.xml` by maven and its only contents are:

`<glassfish-web-app>  <context-root>/yoman</context-root>  </glassfish-web-app>`

Anyting I'm missing here? Or do you know a way to check if payara micro is even reading the file?

Comment: All right, the file needs to go to `WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` and then it works like a charm. @Mike, do you want to write that into an answer?